# Apache 2.4 reverse proxy http to https not resend cookie

Tags: apache, cookies, https, vhosts

after many hours spent to test i can not work with my vhost local in proxy to https backend.

I work from http://myhost-webapp.localhost -> **https**://10.0.0.99:9443

**LOCAL VHOST**

```
    Define myhost myhost-webapp
    Define hostextension localhost
    Define DocumentRoot ${xampproot}/htdocs/myhost/webapp

    Define remotehost 10.0.0.99
    Define remoteport 9443
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin ${myhost}@${hostextension}
        ServerName  ${myhost}.${hostextension}
        ServerAlias www.${myhost}.${hostextension} 

        DocumentRoot ${DocumentRoot}
        DirectoryIndex index.localhost.html index.php index.html index.htm

        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLProxyVerify none 
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
        #SSLCertificateFile      "conf/apache-selfsigned.crt"
        #SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/apache-selfsigned.key"     
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"         
        Header add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"            

        ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
        ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain ${myhost}@${hostextension} ${remotehost}
        ProxyPass /rest/security https://${remotehost}:${remoteport}/rest/security
        ProxyPassReverse /rest/security https://${remotehost}:${remoteport}/rest/security
        ProxyPassMatch ^/rest/security(|[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+) https://${remotehost}:${remoteport}/rest/security/$1



        <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all      
        Require all granted         
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog  ${xampproot}/logs/${myhost}.${hostextension}.error.log
        CustomLog ${xampproot}/logs/${myhost}.${hostextension}.access.log combined
            </VirtualHost>
```

the first call work fine because not work with cookie, but after login all next calls must have the cookie in request.
The call to auth work fine and i recive the cookie in header response

**HEADER LOGIN RESPONSE**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 12 Dec 2018 14:32:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2n PHP/7.2.11
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: a3u="AA8XiiVW3VSLw99k05LfcGjpKebdkuJba4532mb0N+MS8+xTD2+uHfhkNT+AYkemIb4CRXTNXedtLa6yXZwXWbc="; Path=/; Secure; HTTPOnly
Set-Cookie: a3pt="AMSQr9vTZhe38+XCCEIOfVmIoq3b22DAEOC8jvhDZtoTKNUfWNotT6GpbSRb1Ido5W7eK/51eFD2A3/+rAlt7mHpKH0SuNQ1BR2PmvlVpECl"; Path=/; Secure; HTTPOnly
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=59
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

after login with success begin another call, but this fail because in my header request not have any cookie

**REQUEST HEADER WRONG**

```
GET /rest/security/app-variables?_dc=1544625129496 HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost-webapp.localhost
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept: */*
Referer: http://myhost-webapp.localhost/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: it,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8
```

In my vhost local https all work fine and this is a correct request header (with **https**://myhost-webapp.ssl.localhost

**REQUEST FROM HTTPS LOCAL VHOST**

```
GET /rest/security/app-variables?_dc=1544622599978 HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost-webapp.ssl.localhost
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept: */*
Referer: https://myhost-webapp.ssl.localhost/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: it,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8
Cookie: JSESSIONID=sI01GSWEaSbhGD8mqUoY3w9b; a3u="AI4p0hyymcJPxd2Y13wtfsPpKebdkuJba4532mb0N+MS8+xTD2+uHfhkNT+AYkemISLeE/1iAS4UourleWCBNdQ="; a3pt="AC3FByfeyEpG60gWuA+vrtJKF16AS+FPtSRYeRh+AMl/XsBu6ODVQicgYWieM0jqOCLwC+8OKir+0alkmtYeVuQhuJSYnjUp2cVBC+EyCdqz"
```

why in my http host not append any cookies? in my cookie storage not have any saved information. someone can help me to resolve this configuration?

i must use http because https vhost not work in firefox and IE and i must test in IE my applicatin web :(

Comment: The `Secure` password is used to make sure the cookie is only sent on an HTTPS connection.  Your browser talks to port 80, HTTP.  Then the proxy talks HTTPS to :9443.  So remove the `Secure` keyword from your cookie headers.  The best solution here is to put it all in HTTPS!  *Note*: I am not 100% certain of this, try it out, let me know!

Comment: yes, correct but the your solution not wotk in Internet explorer and firefox, and i must test the web site https in IE. I search a workaround. I want use http because http is not blocked in IE, but the backend is into a machine in https. Your ide work, but only in Chrome